# Slick carousel. Не корректно работает несколько каруселей на одной странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

Нужно подключить в разные табы по карусели, но первая работает нормально, остальные нет. Инициализировал и через классы, и через ИД. Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

```
$('#slider_1').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});

$('#slider_2').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

И т.д.

http://codepen.io/fanfer/pen/bqpxMP

Comment: Пример http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/2/

Comment: Этот вариант работает, если карусели находятся не в табах и их видно сразу, а если вставить в бутстраповские табы - нет

Comment: slick анализирует ширину на видимом слайдере, в табах он не видим, думаю стоит его инициировать при смене таба

Comment: Спасибо, заработало